# Show data from one sheet on another if date is today

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a list of people responsible for data verification that are changing every day.

The schedule is on one sheet. And data verification is on another.
What I need is to show only responsible people if date is today (in certain cell) on verification sheet from the schedule sheet. How can that be done?

Comment: Needs more info to visualise prob and solution try publishing the sheet. Show the code you are stuck on. Unless you really want to do this with a script I suggest that an array formula will solve most problems of this kind. Drop apps script tag??

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to my solution, based on the the detail on the question, I have to make a few presumptions. My solution involves the following:

- I used Google forms, but the script works on the response spreadsheet so is applicable to your problem

A copy of the spreadsheet is made each day at a certain time using triggers** that activate the script, and the main sheet is cleared to make way for the new data for the next day. Before clearing the data from the response sheet, I have a copy of the sheet sent to a folder called folder 1.

- Solution

So on any day when you open the spreadsheet you are only looking at the current day's data.

```
**Triggers: From the spreadsheet go to "Tools> Script editor" from the menu 
In script editor: Go to "Resources>Current projects triggers" from the menu
Choose a time for the spreadsheet function (see link underneath for script) to copy and delete
```

Below is a link to my script. The problem I have at the moment is clearing the responses, but from your question, it sounds as though you are not using a form so my problem is not yours. The script will work for you
[Google forms script to delete responses counter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50468/google-forms-script-to-delete-responses-counter)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the schedule on sheet 1 with column A containing the date and column B with the person responsible then you can use the following vlookup in any cell to return the person(s) assigned to today:

```
=vlookup(today(),Sheet1!A:B,2)
```